# Read as many elements into an integrer array as its size(entered by user) , from a text file

Tags: java

So I was trying to take size from the user and get the the first few elements from a file that can fully fill up the array but it keeps giving me an exception.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (Result too large)

public class TestClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num_of_elements;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nenter a value for number of elements");

    while((num_of_elements = sc.nextInt())<0)
    {
        System.out.println("\nenter a positive value ");
    }
    //num_of_elements = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\n"+ num_of_elements);

    int[] array_booleans = new int[num_of_elements];
    int[] array_integers = new int[num_of_elements];

    /*String bool_file;
    System.out.println("\nEnter the name of the file with the booleans");
    bool_file = sc.nextLine();*/
    String int_file;
    System.out.println("\nEnter the name of the file with the integers");
    int_file = sc.nextLine();


    try {
        File f  = new File(int_file);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
        int i=0;
        while( scanner.hasNextInt()){

           array_integers[i++]= scanner.nextInt(); 
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<array_integers.length;i++)
        System.out.println(array_integers[i]+ " ");


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done two corrections to make it work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            int num_of_elements;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("\nenter a value for number of elements");

            while((num_of_elements = sc.nextInt())<0)
            {
                System.out.println("\nenter a positive value ");
            }
            //num_of_elements = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("\n"+ num_of_elements);

            int[] array_booleans = new int[num_of_elements];
            int[] array_integers = new int[num_of_elements];

            /*String bool_file;
            System.out.println("\nEnter the name of the file with the booleans");
            bool_file = sc.nextLine();*/
            String int_file;
            System.out.println("\nEnter the name of the file with the integers");
            int_file = sc.next();


            try {
                File f  = new File(int_file);
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
                int i=0;
                while( i<array_integers.length){

                   array_integers[i++]= scanner.nextInt(); 
                }


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for(int i=0;i<array_integers.length;i++)
                System.out.println(array_integers[i]+ " ");



    }
```

And file is:

```
12 23 34 45 56 777 6666
2 4 5 6 22 66 888 22222
```

The program prints:

```
enter a value for number of elements
6

6

Enter the name of the file with the integers
C:\\foo.txt
12 
23 
34 
45 
56 
777
```

Comment: `int_file = sc.next();` and `while( i<array_integers.length)`